# How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) was recently released and I liked the look of it and the features it offered, so I figured I would give it a go.

I downloaded the application from the [downloads page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), fired it up, messed around a bit with some of the features ... and then realized I had no idea how to actually execute any of my Python code!

I really like the look and feel/usability/features of Visual Studio Code, but I can't seem to find out how to run my Python code, a real killer because that's what I program primarily in.

Is there is a way to execute Python code in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This answers your question visually https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8yyjhxSPdI

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Here is how to configure *Task Runner* in Visual Studio Code to run a .py file.

In your console, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Apple). This brings up a search box where you search for "Configure Task Runner"

[image]

If this is the first time you open the "Task: Configure Task Runner", you need to select "other" at the bottom of the next selection list.

This will bring up the properties which you can then change to suit your preference. In this case you want to change the following properties;

1. Change the Command property from `"tsc"` (TypeScript) to `"Python"`
2. Change showOutput from `"silent"` to `"Always"`
3. Change `args` (Arguments) from `["Helloworld.ts"]` to `["${file}"]` (filename)
4. Delete the last property `problemMatcher`
5. Save the changes made

[image]

You can now open your .py file and run it nicely with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Apple).

Comment: Hi, is there a way to enable input for VS Code?

Comment: Is this Task Runner thing a Visual Studio thing or is it a Python thing?

Comment: It's a config file for VS, but it's an instance per project, kept inside the `.vscode` directory in your project file structure

Comment: as of March 2020, a newer version of task config with updated key-value pairs should be used, please refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode and use "Tasks: Configure Task"

Comment: Which section for python refer to the newly built vscode? thanks

Comment: For Visual Studio Code version 1.51.1 (on Linux): No matches for "Configure Task Runner". But there is for "Configure Task". It may or may not be the same thing.

Answer (score 99):

All these answers are obsolete now.

Currently you have to:

1. install the [Python language extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) (and Python, obviously)
2. open folder (important!), open any Python file inside that folder
3. switch to debug "tab"(?) and click on the gearbox (with hint 'Configure of Fix 'launch.json'')
4. save the opened *launch.json* file (it's placed in .vscode subdirectory in the folder opened in step #2)
5. finally, click the green triangle or hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

No additional extensions or manual *launch.json* editing is required now.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could show an example (json snippet) of a working configuration. I keep getting errors.

Comment: I believe this answer only works if you have the "Code Runner" extension installed.

Comment: @EntropyWins I think he was referring to the full fledged [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python). A quick google search reveals that VS Code's own Python use [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) recommends this extension and follows much of the same steps we do.

Comment: I think you are correct, there are several green triangles on my UI, the most useful of which only appeared after I installed code runner.  I see now this answer uses the native debugger to 'run' the code.

Comment: Yes, I had to add the Code Runner extension and then manually add my python path as @Jun Han's comment explained, but with the added step of substituting all '\'s in the path for '/'

Comment: and launch.json supports environment variables https://stackoverflow.com/a/39857499

Comment: Code Runner isn't obsolete; it's a different tool for different requirements. Namely, it's faster to start in my experience and simpler -- good for quick checks and such while the Python extension is better for more in-depth work like debugging and interaction.

Answer (score 79):

You can [add a custom task](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201505/Blog/Custom-Tasks-In-Visual-Studio-Code/) to do this. Here is a basic custom task for Python.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "c:\\Python34\\python",
    "args": ["app.py"],
    "problemMatcher": {
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*)+s$",
            "message": 1
        }
    }
}
```

You add this to file `tasks.json` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to run it.

Comment: Be aware that the above regular expression (/^(.*)+s$/)cause exponential runtime behavior. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4651

Comment: I'm not really sure what `(.*)+` is supposed to achieve. `*` already matches the previous item 0 or more times and `+` matches the previous item one or more times, so you want to match 0 or more characters... one or more times?

Comment: doesn't work on Mac
"Failed to launch external program "c:\\Python34\\python" app.py.
spawn c:\Python34\python ENOENT"

Comment: @Awesome_girl You'll need to edit that line for MacOS, but also your unique environment. For example, "my" python is at `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`. You can probably find the one you want using the command `which python` in Terminal.app.

Answer (score 28):

To extend [vlad2135's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code/42180398#42180398) (read his first); that is how you set up Python debugging in Visual Studio Code with [Don Jayamanne's great Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) (which is a pretty full featured IDE for Python these days, and arguably one of Visual Studio Code's best language extensions, IMO).

Basically, when you click the gear icon, it creates a *launch.json* file in your `.vscode` directory in your workspace. You can also make this yourself, but it's probably just simpler to let Visual Studio Code do the heavy lifting. Here's an example file:

[image: File launch.json]

You'll notice something cool after you generate it. It automatically created a bunch of configurations (most of mine are cut off; just scroll to see them all) with different settings and extra features for different libraries or environments (like Django).

The one you'll probably end up using the most is Python; which is a plain (in my case C)Python debugger and is easiest to work with settings wise.

I'll make a short walkthrough of the JSON attributes for this one, since the others use the pretty much same configuration with only different interpreter paths and one or two different other features there.

- name: The name of the configuration. A useful example of why you would change it is if you have two Python configurations which use the same type of config, but different arguments. It's what shows up in the box you see on the top left (my box says "python" since I'm using the default Python configuration).
- type: Interpreter type. You generally don't want to change this one.
- request: How you want to run your code, and you generally don't want to change this one either. Default value is `"launch"`, but changing it to `"attach"` allows the debugger to attach to an already running Python process. Instead of changing it, add a configuration of type attach and use that.
- stopOnEntry: Python debuggers like to have an invisible break-point when you start the program so you can see the entry-point file and where your first line of active code is. It drives some C#/Java programmers like me insane. `false` if you don't want it, `true` otherwise.
- pythonPath: The path to your install of Python. The default value gets the extension level default in the user/workspace settings. Change it here if you want to have different Pythons for different debug processes. Change it in workspace settings if you want to change it for all debug processes set to the default configuration in a project. Change it in user setting to change where the extension finds Pythons across all projects. (4/12/2017 The following was fixed in extension version 0.6.1). <s>Ironically enough, this gets auto-generated wrong. It auto-generates to "${config.python.pythonPath}" which is deprecated in the newer Visual Studio Code versions. It might still work, but you should use "${config:python.pythonPath}" instead for your default first python on your path or Visual Studio Code settings. (4/6/2017 Edit: This should be fixed in the next release. The team committed the fix a few days ago.)</s>
- program: The initial file that you debugger starts up when you hit run. `"${workspaceRoot}"` is the root folder you opened up as your workspace (When you go over to the file icon, the base open folder). Another neat trick if you want to get your program running quickly, or you have multiple entry points to your program is to set this to `"${file}"` which will start debugging at the file *you have open and in focus in the moment you hit debug*.
- cwd: The current working directory folder of the project you're running. Usually you'll just want to leave this `"${workspaceRoot}"`.
- debugOptions: Some debugger flags. The ones in the picture are default flags, you can find more flags in the python debugger pages, I'm sure.
- args: This isn't actually a default configuration setting, but a useful one nonetheless (and probably what the OP was asking about). These are the command line arguments that you pass in to your program. The debugger passes these in as though they you had typed: `python file.py [args]` into your terminal; passing each JSON string in the list to the program in order.

You can go [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution) for more information on the Visual Studio Code file variables you can use to configure your debuggers and paths.

You can go [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for the extension's own documentation on launch options, with both optional and required attributes.

You can click the <kbd>Add Configuration</kbd> button at the bottom right if you don't see the config template already in the file. It'll give you a list to auto generate a configuration for most of the common debug processes out there.

Now, as per vlad's answer, you may add any breakpoints you need as per normal visual debuggers, choose which run configuration you want in the top left dropdown menu and you can tap the green arrow to the left to the configuration name to start your program.

**Pro tip:** Different people on your team use different IDEs and they probably don't need your configuration files. Visual Studio Code nearly always puts it's IDE files in one place (by design for this purpose; I assume), launch or otherwise so make sure to add directory `.vscode/` to your .gitignore if this is your first time generating a Visual Studio Code  file (this process will create the folder in your workspace if you don't have it already)!

Comment: This is informative, but doesn't actually explain how to run python code from VSCode.

Comment: FYI, for some reason in my project I needed to manually add the "program" line to the python module and the pyramid section to clear all errors

Comment: @aaronsnoswell You click the green arrow in the top left of the debug menu after this. That was covered under Vlad's answer which this was originally just an expansion/explanation on a critical part that his answer just glances over as 'set up launch.json.'

Comment: @scld It's weird that was missing in the first place, but yes, that one is not optional. Debugger kind of needs to know when to start the program.

Comment: To extend, Vlad's answer works, this is just why that answer works, and what you can do with it past go.

Comment: Great! I am looking for how to specify command line args in VSCode python.

Comment: After you click the arrow the python file run's,  you make your changes in your code and run it again,, BUT you either have to click the garbage can to clear out the previous output ,  I'm looking for a way to modify it so that every time you click the arrow it would clear the previous out and run the file again.  Would this be done in the launch.json  or ?

Comment: @Jarhead1775 I haven't used the Python extension (or python) in a while since my day job is in Java, but it should be debug.terminal.clearbeforereusing as a language agnostic setting in more recent versions of VSCode.

Answer (score 27):

There is a *Run Python File in Terminal* command available in the [Python for Visual Studio Code](http://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCode/) extension.

[image: Run Python File in Terminal]

Comment: I think the issue people are having is how to run a file with command line arguments.

Comment: Can I assign a shortcut for the same ?

Comment: yeah for sure. the command to bind to is `python.execInTerminal`

Comment: But how to assign a shortcut for it on Windows?

Comment: Getting error while using sublinux bash on Windows:  "C:\Users\User"Anaconda3\python.exe No such file or directory"

Comment: @MahirIslam if you hover the mouse over the command I find a config-wheel where I can assign this.

Answer (score 20):

As stated in [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python), just right-click anywhere in the editor and select *Run Python File in Terminal*.

Comment: After a search spiral for multiple hours I read this and everything suddenly works...kind of pissed off the answer was this simple all along :P. This should definitely be near the top of this page.

Comment: How to add a shortcut?

Comment: I don't have this option when I right click?! However, when I run the command through ctrl-shift-p now I have it.

Comment: Agree, I don't know why this answer is not at the top :)

Comment: it is too much work! I loved jupyter notebook's `shift + enter` trick. It is all you have to do run your code. Dont they have something like that in VScode?

Comment: But before that you need to have python extension installed

Answer (score 16):

1. Install the Python extension (Python should be installed in your system). To install the Python Extension, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then type 'python' and enter. Install the extension.
2. Open the file containing Python code. Yes! A .py file.
3. Now to run the .py code, simply right click on the editor screen and hit 'Run Python File in the Terminal'. That's it!

*Now this is the additional step. Actually I got irritated by clicking again and again, so I set up the keyboard shortcut.*

4. Hit that Settings-type-looking-like icon on bottom-left side → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → type 'Run Python File in the Terminal'. Now you will see that + sign, go choose your shortcut. You're *done*!

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for *Settings* is Ctrl + `,`  (comma).

Answer (score 15):

There is a lot of confusion around Visual Studio Code tasks and the debugger. Let's discuss about it first so that we understand when to use tasks and when to use the debugger.

### Tasks

The [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) says -

> Lots of tools exist to automate tasks like linting, building,
> packaging, testing, or deploying software systems. Examples include
> the TypeScript Compiler, linters like ESLint and TSLint as well as
> build systems like Make, Ant, Gulp, Jake, Rake, and MSBuild.
>
> ....  Tasks in VS Code can be configured to run scripts and start
> processes so that many of these existing tools can be used from within
> VS Code without having to enter a command line or write new code.

**So, tasks are not for debugging, compiling or executing our programs.**

### Debugger

If we check the debugger documentation, we will find there is something called [run mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode). It says -

> In addition to debugging a program, VS Code supports running the
> program. The **Debug: Start Without Debugging** action is triggered with
> <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> and uses the currently selected launch configuration. Many of
> the launch configuration attributes are supported in 'Run' mode. VS
> Code maintains a debug session while the program is running, and
> pressing the Stop button terminates the program.

**So, press <kbd>F5</kbd> and Visual Studio Code  will try to debug your currently active file.**

**Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and Visual Studio Code will ignore your breakpoints and run the code.**

### Configuring the debugger

To configure the debugger, go through [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging). In summary it says, you should modify the `launch.json` file. For starters, to run the code in integrated terminal (inside Visual Studio Code), use -

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

To run the code in an external terminal (outside of Visual Studio Code), use -

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "externalTerminal"
}
```

**N.B.** If all documentation was easy to search and understand then we probably would not need Stack Overflow. Fortunately, the documentation I mentioned in this post is really easy to understand. Please feel free to read, ponder and enjoy.

Answer (score 14):

So there are four ways to run Python in Visual Studio Code so far:

1. Via an [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) (come on, it's **integrated**! So technically you run it from within Visual Studio Code ;)

   - No need to install *any* extension.
   - No need to create and configure *anything* (assuming that you already have `python` in your `$PATH`).
   - `⌃Space` (open terminal) and `python my_file.py` (run file).
2. Via custom [Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode) (accepted [Fenton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code/29989061#29989061)):

   - No need to install *any* extension.
   - Default Visual Studio Code's way of doing things.
   - **Beware not to copy-paste the answer** because its `problemMatcher.pattern.regexp` is broken and it hangs the editor. It's better to either delete `problemMatcher` or change the `regexp` to at least `^\\s+(.*)$`.
3. Via [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension (@JanHan's answer):

   - Need to configure `code-runner.executorMap` in [User Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) (add path to your `python`).
   - Very helpful extension especially if you run not only Python in Visual Studio Code.
4. Via Microsoft's [official Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) ([vlad2135's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code/42180398#42180398)):

   - Need to create `launch.js` (a couple of clicks in Visual Studio Code's Debug tab).
   - The extension is a must-have for those who wants to use Visual Studio Code as a primary IDE for Python.

Comment: Nikolay, out of the 4, and assuming the cost of installing an extension is negligible, which one is most productive in your opinion?

Comment: @sivabudh I'd use the 4th way for sure. [Official extenstion](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) gives you so much: autocomplete, linting, debugging and more. But it depends on your case. If you only want to write a couple of scripts then no need to install anything - just use a terminal

Comment: With number 4, how do you configure a hot key to run it?

Answer (score 10):

If I just want to run the Python file in the terminal, I'll make a keyboard shortcut for the command because there isn't one by default (you need to have the Python interpreter executable in your path):

- Go to *Preferences* (the gear icon on the bottom left) → *Keyboard Shortcuts*
- Type 'run Python file in terminal'
- Click on the '+' for that command and enter your keyboard shortcut

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

Answer (score 10):

- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run with Debugging
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run with Debugging ignoring breakpoints.

---

Running the current python file as is does not have a keybinding associated by default, but you can set this with:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type "Run Python file in Terminal"
3. Hover over it and click the ⚙️ icon
4. Double click "Keybinding"
5. Set your desired shortcut

Answer (score 9):

In the latest version (1.36) of Visual Studio Code (Python):

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run your code in the integrated terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run your code in the interactive [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) shell.

Answer (score 8):

You no longer need any additional extensions. You can simply switch the output of the debugger to the integrated terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then select Integrated Terminal/Console from the dropdown at the top.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the **latest version** of Visual Studio Code (**version 1.21.1**). The `task.json` format has changed, see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_convert-from-010-to-200). So the [answer by Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code/29989061#29989061) and [by python_starter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code/34975137#34975137) may no longer be valid.

#### Before starting configuration

Before you start configuring Visual Studio Code for running your Python file.

- Make sure that you have installed Python and added its executable to your system PATH.
- You must set the folder where your python source file resides as your working folder (go to `File -> Open Folder` to set your working folder).

#### Configuration steps

Now you can configure the task. The following steps will help you run your python file correctly:

1. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and input `task`, you will see a list of options, select `Tasks: Configure Task`.

[image]

2. You will then be prompted `create task.json from template`, choose this option, and you will be prompted to choose from a list of options. Choose `Others`.

[image]

3. Then in the opened `task.json` file, use the following settings:

   ```
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run this script",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python",
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
    }
   ```

In the above settings, you can give a meaningful `label` to this task. For example, `run python`.

4. Go to the `Tasks` menu and click `Run Task`. You will be prompted to choose the task. Just choose the newly created `run this script` task. You will see the result in the `TERMINAL` tab.

[image]

[image]

For a more complete tutorial about task configuration, go to the [Visual Studio Code official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode).

Answer (score 7):

Super simple:

Press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key and the code will run.

If a breakpoint is set, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> will stop at the breakpoint and run the code in *debug* mode.

**Other Method - To add Shortcut**

Note: You must have Python Extension By Microsoft installed in Visual Studio Code, and the Python interpreter selected in the lower-left corner.

Go to File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts (alternatively, you can press Ctrl + K + S)
In the search box, enter python.execInTerminal
Double click that result (alternatively, you can click the plus icon)
Press Ctrl + Alt + B to register this as the keybinding (alternatively, you can enter your own keybinding)

Now you can close the Keyboard Shortcuts tab
Go to the Python file you want to run and press Ctrl + Alt + B (alternatively, you can press the keybinding you set) to run it. The output will be shown in the bottom terminal tab.

Comment: This was actually the best answer with a caveat: Install Microsoft's Python extension first. Lol

Comment: This will fail if the workspace is set up for something else, e.g. a .NET Core project (for instance, after adding a new folder to the existing workspace with some Python files).

Answer (score 7):

Here's the current (September 2018) extensions for running Python code:

[Official Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python): This is a must install.

[Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter): A extension for running Jupyter notebooks. This is a must install if you are a data scientist.

[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner): Incredibly useful for all sorts of languages, not just Python. I would highly recommend installing.

[AREPL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=almenon.arepl): Real-time Python scratchpad that displays your variables in a side window. I'm the creator of this, so obviously I think it's great, but I can't give a unbiased opinion ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Wolf](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=traBpUkciP.wolf): Real-time Python scratchpad that displays results inline

And of course if you use the integrated terminal you can run Python code in there and not have to install any extensions.

Comment: Update: Jupyter is not maintained anymore. All of its functionality will be contained in Python extension according to the notification on VScode.

Comment: Update: there's now an official Microsoft [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension.

Answer (score 7):

in new Version of VSCode (2019 and newer) We have run and debug Button for python,

**Debug :F5**

**Run without Debug :Ctrl + F5**

So you can change it by go to **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**
search for `RUN: start Without Debugging` and change Shortcut to what you want.
its so easy and work for Me (my VSCode Version is 1.51 but new update is available).

Answer (score 5):

Note: You must have [Python Extension By Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed in Visual Studio Code, and the Python interpreter selected in the lower-left corner.

1. Go to *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* (alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
2. In the search box, enter `python.execInTerminal`
3. Double click that result (alternatively, you can click the *plus* icon)
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to register this as the keybinding (alternatively, you can enter your own keybinding)
5. Now you can close the *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab
6. Go to the Python file you want to run and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>  (alternatively, you can press the keybinding you set) to run it. The output will be shown in the bottom terminal tab.

Comment: Something very similar is done in this [running vscode python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8yyjhxSPdI) tutorial.

Comment: Can't believe this was so hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

I had installed Python via *[Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution))*.

By starting Visual Studio Code via Anaconda I was able to run Python programs.

However, I couldn't find any shortcut way (hotkey) to directly run .py files.

*(Using the latest version as of Feb 21st 2019 with the Python extension which came with Visual Studio Code.
Link: [Python extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python))*

**The following worked:**

1. Right clicking and selecting *'Run Python File in Terminal'* worked for me.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (on Windows)

The below is similar to what @jdhao did.

**This is what I did to get the hotkey:**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> // Run build task
2. It gives an option to configure
3. I clicked on it to get more options. I clicked on *Other config*
4. A 'tasks.json' file opened

I made the code look like this:

```
    {
        // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
        // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Run Python File", //this is the label I gave
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "python",
                "args": ["${file}"]
```

After saving it, the file changed to this:

```
    {
        // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
        // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Run Python File",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "python",
                "args": [
                    "${file}"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

5. After saving the file 'tasks.json', go to your Python code and press
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.
6. Then click on *Run task* → *Run Python File* // This is the label that
   you gave.

Now every time that you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, the Python file will automatically run and show you the output :)

Answer (score 4):

There is an easiest way to make a shortcut for `run in terminal` command:

1. Click on the settings icon on the left bar.
2. Then click on `Keyboard Shortcuts`.
3. Paste `python.execInTerminal` in search bar on top.
4. Now double-click on the `Keybinding` column opposite the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` command and set the shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

I use Python 3.7 (32 bit). To run a program in Visual Studio Code, I right-click on the program and select "Run Current File in Python Interactive Window". If you do not have [Jupyter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook), you may be asked to install it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple and direct [Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) would save both time and efforts.
Linting, debugging, code completion are the available features once installation is done. After this, to run the code proper Python installation path needs to be configured in order to run the code. [General settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) are available in *User* scope and *Workspace* can be configured for Python language– `"python.pythonPath": "c:/python27/python.exe"` 
With above steps at least the basic Python programs can be executed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running code and want to take input via running your program in the terminal, the best thing to do is to run it in terminal directly by just right click and choose "Run Python File in Terminal".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From **Extensions**, install **Code Runner**. After that you can use the shortcuts to run your source code in Visual Studio Code.

**First: To run code:**

- use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
- or press <kbd>F1</kbd> and then select/type *Run Code*,
- or right click in a text editor window and then click *Run Code* in the editor context menu
- or click the Run Code button in editor title menu (triangle to the right)
- or click *Run Code* in context menu of file explorer.

**Second: To stop the running code:**

- use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
- or press <kbd>F1</kbd> and then select/type *Stop Code Run*
- or right click the *Output Channel* and then click *Stop Code Run* in the context menu

Answer (score 2):

If you install Python language extension for VSCode, it also installs Jupyter and Pylance by default, which lets you run Python code in interactive manner.

All you have to do is use `# %%` before the code that you want to execute interactively.

As soon as you insert `# %%`, you can see that VSCode creates a new Jupyter Cell for you.

[image]

And from there you can click on the `Run Cell` cell menu and you can see the result.

So, all you have to do is type the following code in your VSCode,

```
# %%
text = 'Hello World from inline interactive Python'
print(text)
```

Comment: Yes, or just hit Shift-Enter without installing the Jupyter Plugin

Answer (score 1):

To run **python3** on windows vs code:

1. Download the python interpreter from their [official site](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Install the [python packages](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) for vs code. This can be installed directly from vscode's extension manager
3. Verify that your python3 has been installed by running this command:

   *py -3 --version*
4. Run your script with the following command from vscode's terminal:

   *py -3 main.py*

For more information, head over [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for details installation procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In order to launch the current file with the respective [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/venv.html), I added this to file `launch.json`:

```
 {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/FOO/DIR/venv/bin/python3"
    },
```

In the `bin` folder resides the `source .../venv/bin/activate` script which is regularly sourced when running from a regular terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project consisting of multiple Python files and you want to start running/debugging with the main program independent of which file is current you create the following launch configuration (change `MyMain.py` to your main file).

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Main File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/MyMain.py",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to install an extension called "Code Runner"
2. After then look at the right top corner of Visual Studio Code, you will see the run button and
   hit that.
3. After that you will see at the bottom of vs code your code has been executed.
4. You can make your own keyboard shortcut for "Code Runner" to speed up your coding.

Answer (score 0):

I used my existing anaconda environment to run python.  rather than using the python user appdata\local\programs\python use the anaconda install python by environment.  This will give you access to all your libraries in the environment.

```
 1. View->Command Palette->Open user settings
 2. search python
 a. Python: default interpreter path = c:\users\yourname\Anaconda3\python.exe
 b. save the file
 3. View->Command Palette->python:select interpreter
 a. arrow down to your workspace name
 b. select your python and environment

 create a python script and run it.

 see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to the following :

- Select all the lines   : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Run the selected lines : <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On your Mac use control+F5(fn+F5)

Answer (score 0):

### Three easy steps:

1. Install "Python" extension
2. Select a .py file
3. Hit the run icon

[image: Install the Python extension]
[image: Select file and run]

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a one file you want to run, make sure you have python installed on your system, then run

`python <filename`

Its just that simple

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check the 'Run In Terminal' in the Code Runner Settings. This is the simplest solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).