# Common variables for launch.json in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen how `launch.json` for Visual Studio Code has access to `${workspaceFolder}`.  Does it also have access to other common variables?  I would like to have access to the current user's AppData folder so I can do:

```
"program": "${appData}\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\bin\\gulp.js"
```

instead of hard-coding it as:

```
"program": "C:\\Users\\jdoe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\bin\\gulp.js"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Variable substitution in launch.json supports environment variables. For your use-case you can use `${env:AppData}`.

> VS Code supports variable substitution inside strings in `launch.json` the same way as for `tasks.json`.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution

- `${workspaceFolder}` the path of the folder opened in VS Code
- `${file}` the current opened file
- `${relativeFile}` the current opened file relative to workspaceRoot
- `${fileBasename}` the current opened file's basename
- `${fileDirname}` the current opened file's dirname
- `${fileExtname}` the current opened file's extension
- `${cwd}` the task runner's current working directory on startup

> You can also reference environment variables through `${env:Name}` (e.g.
>   `${env:PATH})`. Be sure to match the environment variable name's casing,
>   for example env:Path on Windows.

Comment: `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` the current opened file's basename without extension

Comment: Would it be possible to access the build directory through a variable or I have to hardcode it like `${workspaceFolder}/build/x64-Release/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo`?