# python vscode modulenotfounderror

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module

I have a certain project structure:

```
 - azima
   - .vscode
   - core
     - project_setup.py
   - helper
     - log_helper
   - venv
```

In project_setup.py:

```
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from helper.log_helper import log

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('hello world')
```

Running this file in terminal:

```
(venv) rmali@rakeshmali:~/git/azima$ /home/rmali/git/azima/venv/bin/python /home/rmali/git/azima/core/project_setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rmali/git/azima/core/project_setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from helper.log_helper import log
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'
```

I get this error. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

But running like this `python -m core.project_setup` works.

Comment: Have you tried `from .helper.log_helper import log`?

Comment: @SamMatzko `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` I get this error

Comment: Then use your import method (`from helper.log_helper import log`), but before it put `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))`. This should add `azima` to the list of paths where Python searches for modules.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` scripts in your directory structure? These would tell Python that you to treat the folders as packages and subpackages.

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185437/no-module-named-numpy-visual-studio-code if you have multiple python installations and VSCode has selected a default python interpreter that is not the one where you have installed the module you're trying to import

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73567911/4347611

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**

The path of folder `azima` does not in the `sys.path`(PYTHONPATH).

**Solution:**

You can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "xxx/site-packages"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:
   **PYTHONPATH=xxx/site-packages**

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) to understand the effects of these two configurations.

3. Modify it directly in the python file. Add these codes in the b.py file.

   **import sys; sys.path.append("xxx/Project/src")**

Answer (score 1):

The reason that running

```
(venv) rmali@rakeshmali:~/git/azima$ python ./core/project_setup.py
```

fails while

```
(venv) rmali@rakeshmali:~/git/azima$ python -m core.project_setup
```

succeeds is that when running `python -m <module-name`, Python adds the current directory to the start of `sys.path`, which allows modules in that directory such as `helper` to be imported as top level modules, i.e. with `import helper`. Running `python <script>` does not add the current directory to the start of `sys.path`. Instead, Python adds the directory containing the script to the start of sys.path.

Here are the relevant sections of the docs.

The  [`-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

> As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.

and the docs for the [`-c` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) add

> the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path (allowing modules in that directory to be imported as top level modules)

Docs for `python <script>`

> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory containing that file is added to the start of sys.path, and the file is executed as the `__main__` module.
>
> If the script name refers to a directory or zipfile, the script name is added to the start of sys.path and the `__main__.py` file in that location is executed as the `__main__` module.