# Want to run numpy on vs code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, module

I have installed anaconda and in cmd I have type pip install numpy and it show condition stratified with conda,  when I import numpy in vs code it give error module not found and this issue is also same for pandas. Tell me what I can do to run this libraries in vs code

Comment: Does your VSCode running on an environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'numpy': Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185437/no-module-named-numpy-visual-studio-code)