# Running cells with Python 3.10 requires ipykernel installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-3.10

I just installed Python 3.10 on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04).

Running a Jupyter Notebook inside of VS Code works with Python 3.9 but not with Python 3.10. I get the error message: `Running cells with 'Python 3.10.0 64 bit' requires ipykernel installed or requires an update`.

---

##### Update February 2022

Jalil Nourmohammadi Khiarak gave a more complete answere, it is now the [new accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039682/11680331).

---

##### Update January 2022

It was a dumb error, I solved my problem (see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811651/11680331)).

---

**Things I tried:**

- Clicking on reinstall, which runs:

```
/usr/bin/python3.10 /home/joris/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/pythonFiles/shell_exec.py /usr/bin/python3.10 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall ipykernel /tmp/tmp-12568krFMIDJVy4jp.log
```

- Running `pip3 install --upgrade ipykernel jupyter notebook pyzmq` (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997553/python-requires-ipykernel-to-be-installed) thread).

##### Edits

- As asked in the comments, here is the output when I click the "reinstall" button:

```sh
/usr/bin/python3.10 /home/joris/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/pythonFiles/shell_exec.py /usr/bin/python3.10 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall ipykernel /tmp/tmp-10997AnLZP3B079oV.log
Executing command in shell >> /usr/bin/python3.10 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall ipykernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joris/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/pythonFiles/shell_exec.py", line 26, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(shell_args, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3.10', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '--force-reinstall', 'ipykernel']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

- Here is what my `_vendor` folder contains:

```sh
joris@joris-N751JK:~$ ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/
__init__.py  __pycache__
```

- Here is the output of reinstalling pip and checking the `_vendor` file:

```sh
joris@joris-N751JK:~$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.3.1
Successfully installed pip-21.3.1
joris@joris-N751JK:~$ ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor
__init__.py  __pycache__
```

Comment: What are the outputs of reinstalling ipykernel? What are the error messages?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT, please see my edit

Comment: Can you find the package of `html5lib` in the folder `_vendor`? It looks like you there are some problems with your pip, can you try to reinstall it?

Comment: I added the content of my `_vendor -` folder

Comment: There are some problems with your pip, you need to reinstall your pip. You can have a look at the python3.9 you have installed.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT What do you mean by "have a look?"

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Reinstalling pip should be done with something like `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`, right ?

Comment: Sorry for being late. Yeah, I mean you can compare it with the `python3.9`, I think you can find the html5lib in the `_vendor` folder.

Comment: Yeah, you can reinstall the pip with that command.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT, thanks for the complementary answer. No worries for being late, I will try soon and update this thread

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the pip? And can you find the `html5lib` folder in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/`?

Comment: I edited with the output of reinstalling pip and checking the `_vendor` file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would like to add a comment for that:

Your solution is correct but it didn't work for me when I have used it on my new Linux. I did the following job to solve the problem.

Probably people after using the following comment:

```
python3.10 -m pip install ipykernel
```

Will get error for 'distutils.util'. So you should install first:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-distutils
```

Then again if you try to install you will get the other error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/

To solve it you should use:

```
  curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

Finally, it would be best if you run:

```
 /bin/python3.10 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/shell_exec.py /bin/python3.10 -m pip install -U notebook /tmp/tmp-5290PWIe78U4HgLu.log
```

Comment: Your answer is more complete, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

**MacOs M1**

```
python -m pip install jupyter notebook -U
```

Use this and **restart VSCode** it works.

Also works if u see this error

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 

The 'python3912jvsc74a57bd0f40663dfee16db09be6af2ff2550db36bd5354ec153147c40353828514dedb99' kernel is not available. Please pick another suitable kernel instead, or install that kernel. 

View Jupyter log for further details.
```

It was working fine a few days ago but okay this solved it!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think ipykernel is compatible with 3.10.

Below is the message I receive when I try to install ipykernel with the following command: `conda install -c anaconda ipykernel`

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - ipykernel -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python=3.10
```

---

**Solution:**

I recommend creating a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) using [conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) or another [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe).

To get you started:

1. Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual).
2. Enter the following commands. [Note: These are the Windows commands - may vary slightly on Mac and Linux.]

```
# Create virtual environment
# Use a version of Python that is less than 3.10
conda create --name your_env_name python<3.10

# Activate new environment
conda activate your_env_name

# Install ipykernel
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel

# Add this new environment to your Jupyter Notebook kernel list
ipython kernel install --name your_env_name --user

# Windows only: When trying to launch `jupyter notebook`, you may receive a win32api error.
# The command below fixes that issue.
conda install -c anaconda pywin32
```

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone second that? Any future update is welcome

Comment: I will accept this answer until a more assertive one is given

Comment: There's no conflict between `python 3.10` and `ipykernel`. I clicked `Install` from the vscode popup `Python 3.10 requires ipykernel to be installed`, and Jupyter automatically worked after that. I do agree that using a virtual env is the best practice. I used `python3 -m venv .venv`

Comment: This worked for `python 3.11`, macos. I did not want to install anything globally, instead would run in a conda env. VS Code kept showing a pop up, I selected one of the options "Change Kernel", went to VS Code Command+Shift+P -> Python Select Interpreter -> ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python , i.e. selected env where I installed above packages.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found what went wrong. I am fairly experienced with Python coding, but still far from a pro when it comes to version handling in general.
The issue here is that `ipykernel` needs to be reinstalled for each new Python version you install. Therefore, what solved my problem is simply:

```sh
python3.10 -m pip install ipykernel
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, if you are using conda environments, open an Anaconda prompt (not the terminal in your IDE) and run:

```
$ conda install -p "your python path" --update-deps --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using Ubuntu 23.10, and fixed it by adding:

```
sudo apt install python3-ipykernel
```

in the terminal.

Comment: While this works, it uses `apt`, which is a system-level package manager. I would try one of the python package managers like `pip` and `conda` from other answers before resorting to this.