# Is ipykernel compatible with Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-3.10

I am having issues using Python 3.10 in Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785084/running-cells-with-python-3-10-requires-ipykernel-installed)). Someone mentioned that it may be a compatibility issue. Is it so?

Comment: The upgrade to 3.10 might stll be working its way through the system.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah I'm not sure either, hence why I'm asking if anyone has a more assertive answer

Comment: I don't know if ipykernel is compatible with Python 3.10 but `3.10` is very fresh version and I would wait few months and still use `3.9` or even `3.8`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Python 3.10 / ipykernel 6.6.0 on ubuntu linux 20.4 (deadsneaks repo) with no luck.

```
(demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10) x@x:~/demo310$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2141, in initialize
    self._init_asyncio_patch()
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2117, in _init_asyncio_patch
    nest_asyncio.apply()
  File "/home/x/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/demo310-N7F4eE9V-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 14, in apply
    raise ValueError('Can\'t patch loop of type %s' % type(loop))
ValueError: Can't patch loop of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: It seems that Python 3.10 is not yet accessible from Jupyter Notebook in VS Code