# "Visual Studio issue": When I'm adding the statement "from sklearn import preprocessing" the program learns endlessly in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio, machine-learning, scikit-learn

It is a Visual Studio issue. It's running fine on other platforms like IPython notebook. Can you please suggest what is the issue.

Though it is a very simple code, it is running infinitely and not giving any output.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing


X = [3,4,5,1,8,7,6,9,2]
X= preprocessing.scale(X)
print (X)
```

sklearn is installed. I have also tried adding:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
```

There is no syntax error. I'm using Python 2.7 on Visual Studio, Ubuntu.

Comment: `[-0.77459667 -0.38729833  0.         -1.54919334  1.161895    0.77459667
  0.38729833  1.54919334 -1.161895  ]` Works fine. Visual studio issue?

Comment: Maybe. Can you please suggest why it comes, if you know? What can be the possible reasons? I have lately installed github. Does it affect this?

Comment: @Satyam could you please share how exactly do you run this code?

Comment: You're writing in Python in _Visual Studio_ for __Ubuntu__??? I'd say, that's quite a mashup XD. I think you should move away from VS to something like PyCharm or simply Sublime Text. You'll have less problems with them, to my mind. Note that my opinion may be slightly biased as I don't quite like VS.

Comment: @mkaran I have written the code in VS and run it by pressing Ctrl+Shift+B. It used to run fine before but today it showed this problem. i don't remember making any major changes in VS except for installing GitHub. If I recall any other changes, in case I'd made, I'll duly inform you.

Comment: @Satyam something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29989061/3433323) ?

Comment: Yes. {
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always",

}