# Can I install selenium webdriver into Visual Studio Code?

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code

I would like to start writing some selenium scripts using Visual Studio Code.

Can I install the webdriver(s) and how?

In the demonstration video's that I have seen Visual Studio was used, not VSC.

Please guide me since I am not familiar with the VSC editor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code?rq=1

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can. 
Step 1: Open the VS Code and Install the Nuget Package Manager using the VS code extension (Ctrl+Shift+X)

Step 2: Then go to the Command Pallette of VS Code(Ctrl+Shift+P), Search for Nuget Package Manager : Add Package and then Search for Selenium.Webdriver

You can read more about it [here](https://automationcurrypuff.home.blog/2018/11/10/seleniumwithvisualstudiocodeandxunit/)

Comment: Re "_Install the Nuget Package Manager_" there are at least 6 NPM (with and w/o GUI) in _Extensions: Marketplace_ from different authors here. Which one is the "official" or recommended one?

Answer (score 3):

For the entry-level selenium automation tester, there are some issues and errors to run the java selenium program on a Linux system. So if you are creating a normal java project on selenium:

- Step 1: Download and set a path for java
- Step 2: Must use ***vs code insider***
- Step 3: Install Java Extension Pack for Visual Studio Code
- Step 4: Create a new standalone Java project
  => click “Create Java Project”[if not available Click Ctrl+Shift+P search: Create Java Project]
  => select standalone (no build tools)
  => name the project
  => a new vs Code window will be created with the new project; the new project will have a lib and src folder, “Hello World” java file, and a Readme
- Step 5: Download Selenium Webdriver
  =>[Download](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) the latest stable Selenium Web Driver for Java – this will be a zip file: (e.g. selenium-java-3.141.59.zip)
  =>unzip the file and there will be multiple jar files – it’s important to add ALL the jar files to the project’s dependencies
  => we need client-combined-3.141.59.jar for compiling our Selenium code
  => we need the rest of the jars for running Selenium
- Step 6: Add jar files
  =>add all 7 jars to the project by clicking the “+” next to Referenced Libraries
  (on downside java project on referenced libraries )
- Step 7: Setting up ChromeDriver
  => [Download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) The ChromeDriver major version has to match your Chrome version.
  =>unzip ChromeDriver zip and move it to a central folder that will be referenced by multiple projects (For Linux no need to give path)
- Step 8: On the downside on Java Project "|->" click to Export jar
  Now your setup is ready to run

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue I just used `pip install` and it worked.

```
pip install selenium
```