# Web API with selenium not running on VS Code

Tags: .net, selenium, ubuntu, geckodriver

I have a .NET 5 application with Selenium to run some automations. I'm running it on Ubuntu 20.04.

When i try to run the application via terminal using de "dotnet run" command, it works.
But when I try to use the VS Code do debug my code, I get an exception when instantiating the WebDriver.

[Print of the exception stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq8Uz.png)

Comment: Check your path to Webdriver

Comment: @vitaliis it can't be wrong, because it works when I use "dotnet run"

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741700/can-i-install-selenium-webdriver-into-visual-studio-code

Comment: make the search by message code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990021/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-bin-google-chrome-unexpectedly-exited

Comment: I have tried both solutions but none of them worked. The Nuget Package Manager Extension tries to add the Package Reference in my .csproj files, but the reference is there. And it can't be some misconfiguration of binary location, because the application runs by the terminal but do not run in vs code.