# Visual Code Code Runner not running code in Virtual Env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My code runner in VS Code is not executing code in virtual environment. I have looked for multiple solutions in existing threads here and outside. Even after multiple attempts it does not work. I have attached reference of each attempts.

**Attempt 1:**

```
"python": "C:\\Users\\Farhan Hasant\\.virtualenvs\\HelloWorld--L5nr0Hr\bin\\python -u",
```

[image: Result]

**Attempt 2:**

```
"python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
```

[image: Result]

**Virtual Environment Path:**
[image: Virtual Env path]

**I have created the virtual environment using pip install pipenv and installed requests package using pip env install requests.**

Comment: Seems that the issue is that the space in the path of the wrapper

Comment: I tried removing the space too but it does not seem to work,

Comment: You can't remove it if it's there in the path, but you can probably escape it with a backslash, e.g. `Farhan\ Hasant`.

Comment: @BrettCannon I tried using the escape character but does not seem to work either. Prompts me with the same error. Thank you for you support though !

Comment: Here you may look some useful advice.
It helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it states that if there is a space within your file path, you should add \" to open and close the said file path with blanks.

```
"python": "\"C:\\Users\\Farhan Hasant\\.virtualenvs\\HelloWorld--L5nr0Hr\bin\\python\" 
&& python -u"
```

This should work!