# Run Python in VSCode in python shell like IDLE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle

I am well aware of the thread [How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code)

But none of them shows how to get the >>> python shell running with the file imported. Cuz I would like to call functions separately.
I understand that I can get the python shell going by simply typling `python` in the terminal but the functions in the python file have to manually imported everytime.

Is there a way to run files in VSCode like in IDLE?

Answer (score 12):

you can run the file in an interactive mode in VSC code terminal by using the parameter -i :
    python -i py_file.py

Comment: @xnegra80 This should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: ALTERNATIVE: VS Code "Tasks" add this to settings.json file: "tasks": [{"label": "Terminal: Python", "type": "shell", "command": "{../python.exe}","args": ["-i","py_file.py"] }] (in file

Answer (score 6):

Install the Python Extension, then press `Ctrl+Shift+P (Command+Shift+P)` and type `Python: Start REPL`. Click the command, and you'll get an interactive Python console.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the official Python extension installed, you can search the command list (Ctrl+Shift+P) for "Python interactive" and you'll see several options that allow to do different variations of this:

[image: python interactive]

Comment: It opens jupyter which I dont think is what I wanted. Any ways to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was figured out or not, but I was having a similar question. How to simply use something like IDLE (the known '>>>' shell prompt) inside VSCodesee w/o chasing down plugins and their settings? I noticed that no answer was marked confirmed and although insightful, not what I was looking for.

I use Mac and while trying different things to address this, I found that by using/copying the path in the Python Launcher settings I got what I was looking for. Then, I validated the equivalent for Windows. Please see below.

**Windows:
If you are using Windows, from your Terminal pane/window in VSCode, enter the path to your python.exe, including the executable name. It is located within the "User > AppData" directory.**

***For example: C:\Users\YOUR_USER_ID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe***

Note that AppData is a hidden folder, so may have to change your view settings in Explorer to show Hidden Items.

**MAC:
If you are using MAC, from your Terminal pane/window in VSCode, enter the path to your interpreter**

***For example: /usr/local/bin/python3***

Note: You can also do this directly from a CMD, PowerShell or a Terminal(Mac) window without having to launch IDLE, VSCode or any other coding/scripting app.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer already provided, you can automatically run in interactive mode by changing your settings:

Go under File>Preferences>Settings. Search for "arguments" in the search bar. Then under "Python › Terminal: Launch Args", click on the link "Edit in settings.json".
Once settings.json is open, add "-i" with the quotation marks. It should look something like that:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "terminal.integrated.localEchoEnabled": "off",
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false,
    "python.terminal.launchArgs": [
    "-i"
    ]
}
```

Now, it will pass the argument -i every time you run.