# Is there any way to use the python IDLE Shell in visual studio code?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, python-idle

I was programming python in Visual Studio Code and every time that I ran something it would use the integrated terminal (logically, because I have not changed any settings) and I was wondering, how could I get it to use the Python IDLE's shell instead of the integrated terminal (which for me is useless)?

I have also got Python IDLE installed in my mac but due to Visual Studio Code having "intellisense", it is way easier.

Comment: Python IDLE is NOT an OS shell but a program that reads key strokes and calls the python interpreter to compile the keystrokes.

Comment: Just curious. Why do you want to do this? What does Python IDLE have that you can't get with VS Code's integrated terminal? Why is it "useless"?

Comment: @GinoMempin I find the IDLE shell easier to use than the terminal. Just prefer the UI

Comment: @Melebius Oh true, just realised about that and corrected it. I meant Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Python in VSCode in python shell like IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557135/run-python-in-vscode-in-python-shell-like-idle) If not, you should [edit] your question to describe what particular features are you looking for as there is probably no easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code you should be able to select the file which is supposed to be used in the terminal.
Under :
Preferences -> Settings -> Terminal

Comment: It is not possible to set Python IDLE as a terminal, because it isn't one.