# VS Code How to make terminal run Python functions like IDLE?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle

Apologies if this has already been solved, but I was unable to find the solution. I am trying to run my python files like I could in IDLE. I remember in a previous device, I had somehow changed a setting so I was able to type in the terminal functions from the python file being run and it would run the function.

Example:

```
def main ():

    def function_2 ():
        print ('Value of x at start of the function: ', x)
        x = x + 10
        print ('Value of x at end of the function: ', x)

    x = 5
    print ('Value of x in main before calling function: ', x)
    function_2()
    print ('Value of x in main before calling function: ', x)
```

In IDLE, I would run the python file, and then run main() in the idle terminal and it would run. I was wanting to do the same, but with VS Code. Any help would be appreciated. Much thanks.

Comment: When you run a file from an IDLE editor, IDLE runs it the same as from a command line with `python -i path/to/file`.  The `-i` means to print an interactive prompt in the interactive shell after running the file and printing output to a Python Shell.  Unless VS code does the same somehow, there is no place to enter a python statement such as `main()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Python in VSCode in python shell like IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557135/run-python-in-vscode-in-python-shell-like-idle)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def main ():

    def function_2 ():
        print ('Value of x at start of the function: ', x)
        x = x + 10
        print ('Value of x at end of the function: ', x)

    x = 5
    print ('Value of x in main before calling function: ', x)
    function_2()
    print ('Value of x in main before calling function: ', x)

main()
```

Comment: that work's but I wanted to be able to run it again  if I wanted to by running main() in the terminal

example:
i have 3 functions, each a lil different solution to a problem

why can i not run function1(), function2(), or function3() in the vscode terminal like in IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "python",
"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["-i"],
```

to `settings.json`, which you can open with `Ctrl+Shift+P` then `>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

This runs the command on the open terminal so you will have to close the python terminal every time.

I haven't figured out how to do it better. So don't consider this resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).