# Running Python File via shortcut in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For me this in an absolute standard to have a shortcut for the run function? Can someone tell me what the shortcut is?

[image]

Comment: Apparently there is no shortcut or it would be displayed in the menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File --> Python --> Keyboard shortcuts

Search for 'Python:Run Python File in Terminal'. You can configure your own convenient keyboard shortcuts.