# Visual Studio Code uses 'python' not 'py' to run Python files, which does nothing (3.7 64 bit in PATH)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When trying to run a Python file using Visual Studio Code's terminal window, it's in the format of `python -u path_of_python_file` but this does not do anything. What *does* do something is the *py* command, which runs the file normally.

How can I make it so that Visual Studio Code uses the *py* command and not *python*? For example, `py C:\Users\...`

I have searched for a setting that alters it but I cannot find one. My currently installed Python-related extensions are 'Python' and 'Code Runner' and I have Python 3.7, 64 bit installed. I have tried with a variety of programs including a simple 'hello world' program and it works fine on IDLE and on the command line (using 'py' not 'python').

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code) question, I have no such option on the command palette.

Comment: I've never seen a `py` executable (binary or script), but many called `python`. I wonder why the latter doesn't do anything on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Code Runner to execute your code. If you disable the extension and use the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to run your code instead it will use the Python interpreter you have selected (you will know when you're using the Python extension as the Play button will be green).