# Current shortcut to run Python in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code on a Mac laptop. If I'm using Python I can run the code by pressing the little arrow in the top right,

[image]

However, I can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut for this. There is an old question, [How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code#), but all the answers there seem either to be obsolete or not to work on a Mac. One of them says that the F5 key should work, but my Mac has a useless touchbar instead of function keys so it's no help to me.

tl;dr is there a shortcut to run Python code on a modern VS Code installation besides F5, or an easy way to set one up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Windows so i can't give you a specific answer. But **Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**, search with keyword `run python file`, you will get related shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Nothing was bound there, so I bound my own. I'll probably accept this after a while.

Comment: @Nathaniel. Okay :)

Comment: I also use Windows mostly, I feel usually you can find the key binding information for some buttons when you hover on them, for example "Split Editor Right(Ctrl + \)" for split button usually on the right top of a editor view. If there is no such info, the corresponding binding is empty and you can set your own usually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can bind the shortcut by yourself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `ctrl+shift+b` in windows or `⌘+shift+b` in MacOS.