# Key shortcut for running python file in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS Code, I'm writing python code. I was wondering if there is a key shortcut to run the file instead of pressing the run button in the right top corner of the screen constantly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code)

Comment: what does the official VSC doc say about Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the file.

If you want to debug the file, use <kbd>F5</kbd> instead.

Comment: That doesn't actually do the same thing.  The button just runs the file in a Python terminal, the default command associated with Ctrl+F5 will run the file *in the Python debugger*, just with the debugging turned off.

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to the picture below to find the shortcut key and change it according to your needs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone googling, this was my approach that has worked rather well

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> brings the *Keyboard Shortcuts* menu.

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

At the top, in the search bar, type *run python file*.

[image]

From there, you can add a keybind to the *Run Python File* tag.

Comment: This should be the right answer!  And it's very useful for other things too.

Answer (score 0):

CTRLK + CTRLS brings the Keyboard Shortcuts menu. is the right answer!