# How do I run my code in the terminal in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

For Details, There are no errors, I use code runner, and the programing language is Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can find different ways of running Python code in VS Code, including running in terminal, here: [How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Shift + P`, search for `terminal`, click, run code with command `python -m my_script.py` and `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, the play button in the upper right corner will have three options to run the code.

[image]

Select **Run Code**, and the code result will be output in the **OUTPUT** window. This option is to use the ***Code Runner*** extension to run code

Selecting **Run Java** will output the result in the original terminal, and **Debug Java** will start code debugging.

If you want to use the ***Code Runner*** extension to run the code and have the result output in the **TERMINAL** panel. Please add the following configuration in `settings.json`:

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```