# Visual Studio Code stop button

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code, and I am new to it. The theme is the dark one. My problem is when I am running python code, it doesn't show it is running and there is not a stop button. Doesn't VS Code have a stop button and a rerun button?
Because if the code is running like a complex operation in a file, it doesn't show it is running. If there was the red square to stop, we would know it is running.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code)

Comment: how exactly are you running your program? launch config? task? integrated terminal?

Comment: I use the play arrow to Run code, what I mean is that there isnt a stop button instead of using combination of keys.

Comment: This happened to me: For years had a green "play" button at top right of screen to run my python script. When running (not in debug mode), a red square "stop" button would be in that spot that I could press to cause my code to stop running. Just today I was installing VS Code on a client's machine and the stop button does not appear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, a python script, ie a *.py file, is just a file with some text in it, and VScode, a text editor, is gonna open it as such. Meaning, when opening a python script with VScode, the python script is not "running".

As for "how to run a python script within VScode", there are already a lot of posts on this subject, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code).

Or as for "how to debug python code with VScode", ie you'll have the options to stop the program with a stop button, put breakpoints etc..., there are already a lot of answers on the internet, for example this [video](https://youtu.be/oCcTiRGPogQ).

Answer (score 0):

If your script is taking a long time or has an infinite loop, you can stop it with CTRL+c on the keyboard.

You do get a Stop button (and Step Into, Step Over, Pause, etc buttons) when you run your code in Debug mode. Next to play button >**Debug Python File**.

The play button that you are pressing does not debug your script; it runs your script. Try debugging if you want those controls.